# Вернуть матрицу из функции

Tags: python

Я написал функцию, которая создает матрицу нужных размеров(NxM) и выводит ее. Можно ли как нибудь извлечь значение этой матрицы из функции, для дальнейшего использования?

Пример:

```
def Matr(X,S):
    X = []
    print('Введите элементы матрицы ',S)
    for i in range(n):
        X.append([float(input()) for j in range(m)])
    print('Матрица ', S,' = ')
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            print(X[i][j], end=' ')
        print()
    return(X)
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
A = []
a = 'A'
A = Matr(A,a)
```

Comment: Можете обратиться к ней как к обычной матрице A[0][0] или непосредственно из функции Matr(A,a)[0][0]

Comment: Так после кода `A = Matr(A,a)` у вас в `A` должна быть эта матрица.

Comment: @CrazyElf нет. A остается также пустой [].

Comment: Хм, не может такого быть, вы же возвращаете из функции новую матрицу `return(X)` хотя скобки тут лишние, но это не важно.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, спасибо, в дебаге просмотрел, все понял. Не учел, что индексация в Python'e с 0 начинается

Answer (score -1):

Да, конечно можете. Вот пример:

```
def matrix_create(N, M):
    matrix = [[1 for j in range(M)] for i in range(N)]
    return matrix

matrix = matrix_create(3, 4)
```

Comment: Но если мне нужно использовать ее несколько раз и возвращать оттуда матрицы A,B и C одного размера для операций над ними?